# PIP is not working on my Rasberry Pi (Raspbian), raises ssl-Errors

Tags: python, ssl, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pip

When I try to install python packages with pip on my Raspberry-Pi (running Raspbian Buster), I get the following error:

```
pip install opencv-python (same for every other package)

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting opencv-python

  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/opencv-python/

  ... (repeatedly same error message with total=x changing)

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

I tried the very same command on my windows machine where it worked as expected. I already tried adding various trusted-host-arguments and other arguments people suggested on other sites, but nothing changed.

Comment: Very basic question... have you configured the correct date and time on your RPi?

Comment: Yes, I have. I double checked that.

Comment: it may be related to pypi.python.org changing to pypi.org... try: `pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org opencv-python`

Comment: As I said, I tried adding various different trusted-hosts without success. I tried this specific command right now and it also doesn't work.